# Use of the word "unfurl"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a question about the meaning of the sentence below, especially the use of the words "a sequence" and "unfurled" in it.
*Please note that the author who wrote this sentence came back to her home town after a long time since she moved to another town.

> The pavement changed where a sign marked the end of city limits and a sequence I'd seen a thousand times unfurled.

Can someone please explain what it means by **"a sequence I'd seen a thousand times unfurled"** in this context ?

How I understand the word "sequence" is that it means a series of events that happen in an order.  Having said that the author is seeing the landscape she had been familiar with as she drives up the street, I had the impression that she is recalling her memories of the when she used to see the same landscape a long time ago (please correct me if I am taking it incorrectly).

Moreover, I cannot comprehend how the word "unfurled" is being used here.  As far as I understand what "unfurl" means is to "make or become spread out from a rolled or folded state, especially in order to be open to the wind".  But I am having trouble understanding why "unfurled" with such meaning is relevant to this sentence.

Comment: It means opened up. It is perhaps a poor use of a metaphor, but is not hard to understand. It would help if you’d provide a link. She is not just recalling; the same sequence of events along the road that she experienced when younger are recurring.

Comment: You know, sometimes a cigar is just a cigar, a sequence is a bunch of stuff in some order, and that series opens up as you drive. Unfurling makes it sound like a powerful memory is revealed, but it might just be smoke from a cigar.

Comment: I would prefer *unfolded* instead of *unfurled.*

Comment: *...and **a consecutive series of events which I had seen many times before began to be re-enacted***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's this story you're quoting from:

Crying in H Mart by Michelle Zauner

And the paragraph after that sentence explains the 'sequence':

> bends (in the road)
> straightaways
> the winding stretch of guardrail
> and the clearing..
> Up and up, the pines taking over
> and down the gravel path
> until the lush mass broke open to our home

And I think she's saying that in town, the views are public basically.

But the road past that sign, between town and her home, is like a private memory lane that she's traveling down: in her mind as much as in physical reality.

Since she has been out-of-town, this view that's engraved in her memory has been folder away like clothing in a suitcase. And as she travels that road to home, it's opening up the suitcase and unpacking all the sights and connections and memories of her years growing up.